# Java exception problem

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts

I got this exception in time of running a web application in java. What does this mean?

```
exception.name = javax.servlet.ServletException: BeanUtils.populate
```

Comment: can you post full stacktrace?

Comment: A little bit of source code would help. Please post the servlet/jsp that is causing the exception.

Comment: This means that a ServletException was been thrown during BeanUtils.populate. That's the only reliable fact which can be given based on the information provided as far. For the remnant it's only guessing and shooting in the dark because the **stacktrace** including all **root causes** is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using something which utilizes Jakarta BeanUtils (like Struts) and some method is throwing an exception.

**Following may be reasons for same :**

1. The **action attribute of an tag must
   match exactly** the path attribute of
   the action definition in the
   struts-config.xml file. This is how
   Struts associates the ActionForm
   bean with the action.
2. This error usually occurs when you
   have specified a **form name that does
   not exist** in your tag. For example,
   you specifiec and 'myForm' is not
   the name of a form associated with
   myAction in the struts-config file
3. You get this message when **Struts is
   unable to map the data in the HTML
   form to the properties in your
   ActionForm bean**. Make sure each of
   the properties on your bean is
   either a String or a boolean. Do you
   have any properties of type
   java.util.Date or other objects?
   That might cause this error. Also
   check to see that you have public
   getters and setter for each of your
   properties.

Check:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/53114/Struts/ServletException-BeanUtils-populate

http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=632599

http://javaexceptions1.blogspot.com/2009/08/javaxservletservletexception.html

Comment: @Andreas_D added few more references :).

Comment: I came across the BeanUtils.populate exception when populating a collection and solved it with  these docs: https://wiki.apache.org/struts/StrutsCatalogLazyList

Answer (score 2):

A short call to google's famous www-indexer (with:"ServletException: BeanUtils.populate") provided this result:

[ServletException BeanUtils populate](http://www.coderanch.com/t/53114/Struts/ServletException-BeanUtils-populate)

The answer to that question over there at coderanch could help to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a Struts related exception (and seeing that we don't know the **cause** of the exception), here are some possible reasons why you're getting the exception.

- **No Bean Specified**. This means that there is no `ActionForm` defined in your `Action`.
- Your bean properties you're copying `from` doesn't match the bean properties you're matching `to`.

Unless we know the **cause** of the exception, you'll just have to debug your code and see what is the fault.